# Why does *:* versus (*:*) yield different results?

Tags: solr

I have a service that queries SOLR with a request starting with q=(*:*)&...

I recently upgraded from SOLR 4.7 to 8.9, and have found that querying with the above syntax yields a different quantity of results than just providing q=*:*&... without the parentheses. Using the eDisMax query parser.

I have looked online for some explanation as I am new to SOLR but no luck yet.

Does anyone know what could be causing this difference?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know *why* Solr parses these two queries different, but if you pass `debugQuery=on` to Solr you can see that indeed Solr is parsing the queries very different and hence you get different results:

Query `*:*`

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/sample-core/select?debugQuery=on&q=*%3A*' | grep parsedquery

"parsedquery":"+MatchAllDocsQuery(*:*) 
DisjunctionMaxQuery(((title_245a_lr:\"aaaa zzzz\"~3)^16000.0 | 
(title_245_lr:\"aaaa zzzz\"~3)^16000.0)~0.01) 
FunctionQuery(if(bool(numeric_id_b),const(50),const(0)))",
...
```

vs query `(*:*)`

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/sample-core/select?debugQuery=on&q=(*%3A*)' | grep parsedquery

"parsedquery":"+DisjunctionMaxQuery(((author_main_unstem_search:*\\:*)^1000.0
 | (isbn_t:*\\:*)^3.0 | (author_unstem_search:*\\:*)^40.0 | 
(subject_addl_t:*\\:*)^4.0 | (subject_topic_index:*\\:*)^12.0 | 
(subject_unstem_search:*\\:*)^15.0 | (subject_t:*\\:*)^10.0 | 
(subject_addl_unstem_search:*\\:*)^8.0 | (issn_s:*\\:*)^3.0 | 
...
```

It almost looks like when you pass `*:*` Solr uses the default fields indicated for `qf` or `pf` (usually defined in solrconfig.xml) whereas when you pass `(*:*)` it expands into something else. But I don't know if this is the correct explanation.

I also noticed that passing `*:*` results in a `parsedquery` that indicates `+MatchAllDocsQuery(*:*)` which is what I would expect, but passing `(*:*)` does not.